# Qt C++: Unable to render Vertical Headers

Tags: c++, qt, model, qabstractitemmodel

I've got a custom model derived from QAbstractItemModel.
data, columnCount,rowCount,parent,index,setData,flags,headerData and setHeaderData have all been overrided.
flags only returns Qt::ItemIsEditable (for future)
But the problem starts with headerData(), it seems messages with Qt::Vertical as orientation never reaches it. So, to my understanding, there can't be any vertical headers.
The code serves well for horizontal though:

```
QVariant MiModeloCalendarioGeneral::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    qDebug() << "{";
    qDebug() << "Role: " << role;
    qDebug() << "Section: " << section;
    qDebug() << "Orientation: " << orientation;
    qDebug() << "}";
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return QVariant();
    }
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        qDebug() << "Horizontal";
        return fileras[section];
    }
    if (orientation == Qt::Vertical) {
        qDebug() << "Vertical";
        return cabeceras[section];
    }
}
```

What am I missing?
I've checked that both 'cabeceras' and 'fileras' have content. And the setHeaderData function does emit the headerDataChanged signal.

EDIT: Typo

Comment: What view do you use?

Comment: A QTableView inside a QTabWidget, this same thing works with a normal QStandardItemModel but since I need to store some data for each cell, I required this approach (maybe there's another but I'm kind of set into using it)

Comment: Try to check a properties of your view. Possible, you forgot to turn on vertical header.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case, as just replacing the model with a QStandardItemModel (literally commenting one line and creating a QStandardItemModel for use) makes it work..